# fork/exec : operation not permitted Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: go, ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04, delve

When trying to debug go application I get the following similar error messages.
I initially tried debugging simple golang program with the following vscode launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch Package",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "auto",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

What I get is:

> could not launch process: fork/exec /tmp/__debug_bin1874603807: operation not permitted

Setting `"debugAdapter": "legacy"` leads to similar result:

> could not launch process: fork/exec /home/user/test/__debug_bin: operation not permitted

Starting dlv from command line has same output:

> user@my-machine:~/test$ /home/user/go/bin/dlv debug
> could not launch process: fork/exec /home/user/test/__debug_bin: operation not permitted

I have tested that running files from /tmp is allowed; I have tried setting `kernel.yama.ptrace_scope = 0` in `/etc/sysctl.d/10-ptrace.conf` because all I can find on this error is related to ptrace (https://github.com/go-delve/delve/issues/515).

Also it is worth mentioning that command works as root:

```
user@my-machine:~/test$ su root
Password: 
root@my-machine:/home/user/test# export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
root@my-machine:/home/user/test# go version
go version go1.17.6 linux/amd64
root@my-machine:/home/user/test# ../go/bin/dlv debug
Type 'help' for list of commands.
(dlv) quit
```

Reinstalling dlv with deleting dlv binary and running `go install github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv@latest` does not help. I have a fresh Ubuntu Server 20.04 installation.

How to fix debugging?

Comment: Have you verified that `/home/user/test/__debug_bin` actually has the necessary permission bits (that is, `+x` for your user of your creds or one of the groups of your creds)?

Comment: Ah, it seems that this binary is an artefact of `go build`; OK so have you verified that `/tmp` is not mounted with `noexec` flag? For instance, on my Debian Buster (11) system, `mount -t tmpfs` shows that many such filesystems are mounted with `noexec`, which is a common measure of prevention of certain class of RCE attacks. It does not include `/tmp` but that's not Ubuntu.

Comment: @kostix /tmp was not mounted, the problem had different origins.

Comment: Have you restarted/reloaded the unit responsible for reading those `sysctl` configs after placing the setting in them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured out that setting `kernel.yama.ptrace_scope = 0` did not work for some reason, however `echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope` helped

Answer (score 0):

Docker was installed using Ubuntu preinstall commands. However, docker was not working properly, container couldn't start.

IMPORTANT: I'm using Ubuntu Server

COTAINER LOGS:

```
exec /portainer: operation not permitted
exec /portainer: operation not permitted
exec /portainer: operation not permitted
exec /portainer: operation not permitted
exec /portainer: operation not permitted
exec /portainer: operation not permitted
```

The solution was to install docker install command.

```
# Install Docker
apt install docker.io
```

Done, problem solved. Now we can run:

```
# Compose up
docker compose up -d
```